# Testng re run failed test on other conditions

Tags: java, testng

In my tests using testNg I store failure age in a db every time a test fails. Is there a way other than re-run all failed cases, but on other condition, for example: re run only if the failure age is 1. I should be able to decide to re run a specific test in the after method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be kind of done in a round about fashion.

You first start off by having your classes implement `IHookable` interface. This will cause TestNG to always just run the `run()` method via which your tests would be executed. So in this `run()` implementation, you basically query the test method from your DB to find out if its failure age warrants a re-run and then accordingly you fail the test. 
You then associate a retry analyzer to your tests so that in case of failures they run again.

That should do.

Here's a sample that shows you have we conditionally fail a test method based on a name. That conditional check you can enhance to decide based on your failure age.

```java
import org.testng.IHookCallBack;
import org.testng.IHookable;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassSample implements IHookable {
    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {
        if ("testMethod1".equals(testResult.getMethod().getMethodName())) {
            testResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
        } else {
            callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        System.err.println("testMethod1()");
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        System.err.println("testMethod2()");
    }
}
```

Here's the output :

```
testMethod2()

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: this is cool, but i was looking for something that can trigger the the test after the first run, this run() would decide before the test, i was looking for something that could re-trigger on condition after the test fails

Comment: @FrancisChristopher - The sample that I shared should be able to do that. You basically need to move the altering of the test status after the call to the test method via the `callBack()` and after you examine its test status and check if it has failed or not. But the retry mechanism would still run. But you should be able to fudge that as well, by examining an ITestResult attribute which you can set.

Comment: Krishnan, Thanks, i was able to do it, as you said.